# google bigQuery realtime does not match ga report

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello I would like to see real-time data status using google bigquery real time table.

However, simple query statements do not match GA reports. I created a query that shows the number of sessions per hour, but I had an error rate of 10 to 30%.

Is the accuracy of google bigquery realtime not so good? Or am I making a mistake?

```
WITH noDuplicateTable as (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG (t ORDER BY exportTimeUsec DESC LIMIT 1) [OFFSET (0)]. *
    FROM
      `tablename_20 *` AS t
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE ("% y% m% d", CURRENT_DATE ('Asia / Seoul'))
    GROUP BY
      T.VisitKey
  ),
  session as (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER () sessionRow,
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP ('% H', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS (time), 'Asia / Seoul') AS startTime,
      sum (session) as session,
      (sum (session) -sum (isvisit)) as uniqueSession,
      (sum (isvisit) / sum (session) * 100) as bounce,
      sum (totalPageView) as totalPageView
      FROM (
        SELECT
        count (visitId) as session,
        visitStartTime as time,
        sum (Ifnull (totals.Bounces, 0)) as isVisit,
        sum (totals.pageviews) as totalPageView
        FROM
          noDuplicateTable
        GROUP BY
          visitStartTime
        )
  GROUP BY startTime
  )
select * from session
```

Comment: I have never been able to get streamed data in BigQuery to match GA. If you think about it, the data in GA is imported every 10-15 minutes, so it's unlikely to match GA realtime anyway?

Comment: Yes. I would like to confirm, for example, that when I checked the number of sessions at two o'clock this afternoon, I thought that the GA report and the real time table would be the same [number of sessions at 1:00 AM].